# bulkloader not importing ndb.model

Tags: google-app-engine, bulkloader

I am still new to Python and GAE. I have an application on local server that is running just fine. I can add entity to my datastore, I can view my website, etc: everything is fine.

Now I am trying to use bulkloader to add entities to my datastore. I followed the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata. My loader is below:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.tools import bulkloader
import my_model

class ArticleLoader(bulkloader.Loader):
  def __init__(self):
    bulkloader.Loader.__init__(self, 'Article',
                               [('title', str),
                                ('author', str)
                                ])

loaders = [ArticleLoader]
```

I am getting the error:

```
No module named my_model
```

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Note: I am only using one directory. So my loader is in the same location as the other file that imports the `my_model` module.

Comment: I don't have a `bulkloader.yaml` file. The tutorial mentions that one cannot be auto-generated for localhost. If I need one, does anyone have an example of what the file should look like? I am passing in a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also happen if your `PYTHONPATH` is not properly set up. If you're on Linux, try running this before you run the Bulkloader:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:.
```

This appends your current directory to your `PYTHONPATH` and should make your `my_model` module visible. Since my memory is terrible and I always forget to do it, I've ended up using a simple shell script that includes this at the beginning and then the bulkload command itself.

If you're on Windows, you should be able to modify your path by using `sys.path.append`. Haven't tested this, but you could try adding this to your script (note that this should work on Linux as well):

```py
import sys
# ...
sys.path.append('.')
```

Comment: Cool! Up vote! Now I am getting a new error along the same line: `raise KindError('No implementation for kind \'%s\'' % kind)
google.appengine.ext.db.KindError: No implementation for kind 'Article'`

Comment: So now it sees the module but not the class inside the module -- which is actually the only class inside the module. Every other file sees the class just fine -- except this loader.

Comment: Do I need a `bulkloader.yaml`? Since I cannot auto-generate one, do you have an example I may use? I am passing in a `csv` file.

Comment: @kasavbere Ah, you're using `ndb`, didn't see that at first. You can actually see the cause of the error in your traceback - the `db` API is the one being called, not `ndb`. I remember somebody posting a similar question - I'll paste the link here if I can find it (I think it is actually a missing feature).

Comment: @kasavbere Here is the active feature request (http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=224). This came from  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571466/dowload-app-engine-ndb-entities-via-bulk-exporter-bulk-uploader, which was answered by someone with much more credibility than I :) Sorry for the unsatisfying answer.

Comment: Many thanks. At least now I know why. Since google is pushing for `ndb`. They should really consider adding a way to load csv files.

Comment: @kasavbere Sure thing. I'm sure it will get implemented at some point - loading from CSV with `db` is extremely useful. There may be some workarounds out there, though I don't know if they are Google-approved. In any case, good luck with everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be located in a file named `my_model.py`.  You are getting that error because there is no module named `my_module`.  Might be worth a read of the Python [module](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) and [package](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) docs.

Comment: I don't like to down vote people who are kind enough to try to help. But you should really read the question better next time.